# Understanding a regular expression output to get strings between matched strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
'Commenter:\n\sabc\n<!-- one -->\ntext1<!-- two -- -- -->\ntext2<!-- three -->text3\nCommenter'.
```

Initially, I was trying to extract all comments with this regexp `re.findall ( '<!--(.*?)-->', string, re.DOTALL)` which gave me the proper output `[' one ', ' two -- -- ', ' three ']`.

Then, I tried to get comments made by a particular user "abc" with the following regexp: `re.findall ( 'Commenter.*abc.*<!--(.*?)-->.*Commenter', string, re.DOTALL)` but I get only `[' three ']`.

I am having trouble understanding the output. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a smarter way to do this, but I'd use two regexes, like this:

```
>>> s='Commenter:\n\sabc\n<!-- one -->\ntext1<!-- two -- -- -->\ntext2<!-- three -->text3\nCommenter'
>>> t=re.search(r'Commenter:.*?abc[^<]*?(.*?)Commenter', s, re.DOTALL).group(1);t
'\n<!-- one -->\ntext1<!-- two -- -- -->\ntext2<!-- three -->text3\n'
>>> re.findall(r'<!([^>]*)>([^<]*)', t)
[('-- one --', '\ntext1'), ('-- two -- -- --', '\ntext2'), ('-- three --', 'text3\n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the first and  second `.*` in your regex to do a shortest possible match. This could be done by adding a reluctant quantifier `?` after to `*`

```
>>> re.findall ( 'Commenter.*?abc.*?<!--(.*?)-->.*Commenter', s, re.DOTALL)
[' one ']
>>> re.findall ( 'Commenter.*?text1.*?<!--(.*?)-->.*Commenter', s, re.DOTALL)
[' two -- -- ']
>>> re.findall ( 'Commenter.*?text2.*?<!--(.*?)-->.*Commenter', s, re.DOTALL)
[' three ']
```